# Native or underlying JavaScript files in JetBrains WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm, ecmascript-5

I am currently using JetBrains WebStorm to develop a JavaScript library. When I declare a variable (E.G. `var instance = new HTMLDivElement()`) it shows up in intellisense as being defined in a JavaScript file (in the case of `HTMLDivElement`, it appears to be in DHTML.js). I cannot seem to find them, however if possible I would like to locate them so I can understand the underlying code for the native objects. Are these files physically located on my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, from my experience with PHPStorm, it's kept in a .jar file somewhere under the original installation folder. I'll try to find it in PHPStorm, so you can get an idea where to look for in your IDE.

In PHPStorm, it's found on

```
INSTALLATION_FOLDER\plugins\php\lib\php.jar(\com\jetbrains\php\lang\psi\...)
```

That's for a PHP function. Hope this helps you find the right one on WebStorm. Take note that there's nothing there but function and method definitions (the actual implementation is not there).